# Dynamic Date Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, powerpivot, generate-series

I am creating a Data Model in PowerPivot and am wondering if there is anyway I can create a dynamic date table in SQL. I was able to create one in PowerQuery however there are some bugs in PowerQuery(read only connection) when a table is modified in PowerPivot.  What I am looking for is to have a start date of 1/1/2013 (interval is days) and as each new year rolls around rows are added to the date table.  Is there anyway to do this?

**I am running Postgres**

So far I came up with this,

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fof_GetDates('1/1/2013', GETDATE())
```

But I want it to display all dates till end of the year.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The **completely dynamic** approach would be a query based on [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES):

```
SELECT the_date::date
FROM   generate_series('2013-01-01 0:0'::timestamp
                     , date_trunc('year', now()::timestamp)
                                    + interval '1 year - 1 day'
                     , interval '1 day') the_date;
```

- Always use ISO 8601 format for dates and timestamps, which works irregardless of locale settings.
- A final cast to `date` (`the_date::date`), because the function returns `timestamp` (when fed `timestamp` arguments).
- The expression

  ```
  date_trunc('year', now()::timestamp) + interval '1 year - 1 day'
  ```

  calculates the last day of the current year. Alternatively you could use `EXTRACT (year FROM now())::text || '-12-31')::date`, but that's slower.

You can wrap this into a custom **"table-function"** (a.k.a. **set-returning function**) that you can basically use as drop-in replacement for a table name in queries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dates_since_2013()
  RETURNS SETOF date AS
$func$
SELECT the_date::date
FROM   generate_series('2013-01-01 0:0'::timestamp
                     , date_trunc('year', now()::timestamp)
                                    + interval '1 year - 1 day'
                     , interval '1 day') the_date;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM f_dates_since_2013();
```

Going one step further, you could create a table or - more elegantly -  a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) based on this function (or the underlying query directly):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_dates(the_date) AS
SELECT * FROM f_dates_since_2013();
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_dates;
```

All you have to do now is to schedule a **yearly cron job** that runs [**`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) at the start of each new year:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_dates;
```